# '-respondsToSelector:' not found in protocol(s)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, warnings

I have received this message ever since I started building my first iPhone program several months ago.

I want to check if a delegate implements a given method. It works but I get this warning.

How can I do it the correct way?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `respondsToSelector:` method is declared in the `NSObject` protocol. You have to make sure that your custom protocols also conform to the `NSObject` protocol. Change the declarations of your custom protocols from:

```
@protocol MyCustomProtocol
...
@end
```

to:

```
@protocol MyCustomProtocol <NSObject>
...
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose respondsToSelector is a method of NSObject, and I guess that you have something like `id<MyProtocol>` as the type? Try `NSObject*<MyProtocol>`.

Comment: This is a workaround and not the solution. The correct solution is above: use NSObject as part of the protocol definition.